# echo and google tracking code

Tags: php, tracking

I've got a simple php Contact Us script with a "Thank You" being displayed on the same page via echo command. Everything is working fine, but my question is, if I include Google GA tracking code inside the echo part, would the tracking code be triggered during the page load or only when echo is actually called up ? Does it make sense ? ( I am trying to track conversion - how many people actually send the email via the website )

My website I am working on is bplegal.com/demo/contact_us.php.
Here is the php code:

```
    <style>
.error_message {padding:3px;
font-family:font-family: ‘Arial Narrow’, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
color:#a0c33f;
text-transform:uppercase;}
</style>

<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><b>Attention!</b> You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><b>Attention!</b> Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><b>Attention!</b> Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><b>Attention!</b> Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><b>Attention!</b> You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><b>Attention!</b> Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><b>Attention!</b> Please enter the verification number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><b>Attention!</b> The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}



$address = "info@jbplegal.com";




$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';




$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "Email Sent Successfully.";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
     ?>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" src="//tracking-code"/>
    <script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
<?php
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Comment: php executes on the server, JS executes on the client. if that `<script>` stuff never gets sent to the client, it'll never get executed.

Comment: Marc, you are saying if the "<script> is never send to a client" it won't be executed. Thats my question - will it be executed at the current setup ? If you don't want to read through the code here is the scenario:

1) Client fills out the form
2) The forms triggers PHP file.
3) If the form is sent successfully an echo command is triggered
4) The echo has DIV with the <script>

Comment: it only gets output if `mail()` returns true. But mail returning true doesen't mean the mail actually got sent. it just means PHP successfully handed the email over to the mail server. The email can still get shredded/burned/ditched as spam down the line and PHP will never know.

Comment: I am not worrying if the actual email goes through. ( it does I tested it ), but ultimately, it will depend on server routes and spam filters. What I am mainly after is that the GA code is fired after the email is sent.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using client-side JavaScript tracking code, it will only be triggered once the client (the browser) receives and executes the code. This is the normal way that GA tracking code is used.

If you are using server-side tracking code (ala [php-ga](https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-ga)) it will be executed when the script runs on the server. You probably aren't using this.

Side note: Your file contains CSS, HTML, JavaScript and PHP, all in one place. Do yourself a favor and separate the various pieces of functionality into separate places. Consider implementing an MVC framework to help you keep it all organized.

Comment: George, thanks, but I am currently trying to make it work. Down the road I will clean it up.